# Java – “Error: Could not find or load main class” Error

Tags: java

[the error and the class http://puu.sh/1ITnS.png](http://puu.sh/1ITnS.png)

When I name the class file Main.class, java says it has the wrong name, and when I name it shop.Main.class it says that the main class can't be found. Can anyone help?

```
package shop;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Main
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {  
        Cart cart = new Cart(new Catalogue());
        printOrder(cart);
    }

    public static void printOrder(Cart cart)
    {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        System.out.println("Your order:");
        for(int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < cart.itemsInCart.products.size(); 
            itemIndex++)
            if (cart.itemsInCart.products.get(itemIndex).quantity != 0)
                System.out.println(cart.itemsInCart.products.get(itemIndex).quantity 
                    + " " + cart.itemsInCart.products.get(itemIndex).name 
                    + " $"+ df.format(cart.itemsInCart.products.get(itemIndex).price) 
                    + " = $" + df.format
                    ((cart.itemsInCart.products.get(itemIndex).quantity 
                    * cart.itemsInCart.products.get(itemIndex).price)));

        double subtotal = 0;
        int taxPercent = 20;
        double tax;
        double total;

        for(int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < cart.itemsInCart.products.size(); 
            itemIndex++)
            subtotal += cart.itemsInCart.products.get(itemIndex).quantity 
            * cart.itemsInCart.products.get(itemIndex).price;
        tax = subtotal * taxPercent / 100;
        total = subtotal + tax;


        System.out.print("Subtotal: $" + df.format(subtotal) 
            + " Tax @ " + taxPercent + "%: $" + df.format(tax) 
            + " Grand Total: $" + df.format(total));
    }  
}
```

Ignore between the following two lines

–––––––––––––––––––––––––

Edit Summary

Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:

Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly.

cancel

––––––––––––––––––––––---

Comment: Java tutorial might help.

Comment: Either remove the `package shop;` line, or run java from the `java` folder

Comment: add the .class to your classpath

Comment: A classpath contains only directories and/or .jar files.  Putting a .class file directly in the classpath is incorrect;  it will always be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

compile: ~/java> javac shop/Main.java

run: ~/java> java shop.Main

Answer (score 4):

Execute these commands:

```
cd ..
java shop.Main
```

You can't run java code from inside a package you are trying to reference.

Answer (score 2):

keep it Main.class and try `java shop.Main` from command line in java folder

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful to place classes in correct folders if compiling manually (package name equals folder name on disk). I recommend using an IDE (Eclipse and Netbeans are both good and free choices).

Your example will work if you place Main.class in folder called "shop" and then from project root folder execute "java shop/Main"